# Having an @ inside of a string - PHP

Tags: php, escaping

So I know that you use a backslash to escape most things in php however the @ symbol is an operator that suppresses error messages.

I'm trying to put an email string like this inside of an array "myname@gmail.com", however php is throwing an error.

How do you escape the @ sign?

EDIT:
Here is the code example that was throwing the error:

```
$arr = array(3=> "usertest3@gmail.com",4=> "testingagain@msn.com");
```

However replacing the double quotes with single quotes fixes the error as answered below.... why is that true?

Comment: It shouldn't be throwing an error.  Can you provide a code example?

Comment: Edited with code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"myname@gmail.com" should be 'myname@gmail.com', and it won't cause an error

Comment: I don't think that makes any difference

Comment: PHP checks for variables and functions inside double quotes, and does not in single quotes.  So if you have a variable $variable which equals 7 for sake of example, `echo "$variable";` will print out "7", and `echo '$variable';` will print out "$variable".  This is why it is faster to use single quotes for static strings, or even to concatenate variables onto long static strings like `'Your order ' . $order_id . ' has been placed.  If you have any questions or comments please call 1-800-555-1234.  Blah blah blah blah';`.

Comment: By the way, I have no idea why @ would throw an error inside a string regardless of "" or '', I don't think I've had any problems with it.  What error did it give?

Answer (score 5):

If you've defined the string correctly, it won't cause an error. It doesn't need to be escaped.

Proof: http://www.ideone.com/Gd5am

Comment: That's a cool site!  I'll have to check that out and see how it works for JavaScript.

Comment: @jmort253 it actually works for both server-side (Rhino) and client-side (Spidermonkey) JS. It's an excellent paste tool for when you don't have the right interpreter or compiler and need to test a snippet.